# Why are rewards scaled when using Reinforcement Learning (RL) algorithms in practice?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, reinforcement-learning, loss-functions

I was going through [this](https://medium.com/@ts1829/policy-gradient-reinforcement-learning-in-pytorch-df1383ea0baf) tutorial in pytorch and saw the following code:

```
def loss(policy,gamma):
    R = 0
    rewards = []
    rs = []
    # Discount future rewards back to the present using gamma
    reverse_list = policy.episode_rewards[::-1]
    for r in reverse_list:
        R = r + gamma * R
        rs.insert(0,r)
        rewards.insert(0, R)
    # Scale rewards
    rewards = torch.FloatTensor(rewards)
    rewards = (rewards - rewards.mean()) / (rewards.std() + np.finfo(np.float32).eps)
```

I've never done RL in practice I'm trying to wrap my head around whats going on and why. I think I can summarize my confusion in 4 bullet points:

1. I guess I never thought about the fact that we can't actually implement discounted rewards to infinity in practice. But discounting a finite horizon and then adding it seemed weird to me. Is that really the way its done?
2. Why are we scaling the rewards at all? Seems really weird to me. Never seen this before (don't think I've ever seen it in supervised either).
3. We are taking an average of the recursive equation $R_n = r_n + \gamma R_{n-1}$ rather than just the single reward $r_n$, which also seems odd and confusing. Can anyone clarify why we prefer $J_R(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} R_i$ rather than $J_r(\theta) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1} r_i$. For some reason I;d expect the second one.

my complain about the scaling (point #1) is that if we were to run this forever (which is the usual formulation I'm familiar with), we'd get everything being "on the same scale" but by dividing it into random episodes/chunks, I feel things might be shifted weirdly and I wouldn't know if we are optimizing the right thing anymore. Can someone give an intuition why this scaling thing is ok?

Comment: cross posted: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/arnpzs/why_are_rewards_scaled_when_using_reinforcement/

Comment: cross posted: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Why-are-rewards-scaled-when-using-Reinforcement-Learning-RL-algorithms

Comment: my main concern which is that we take the average of the discounted rewards, rather than the individual rewards. In supervised we have $\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} loss_i $. But here this is not what we have. Thats what is driving my main confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it more closely, In policy gradients, we subtract something called a 'baseline', which helps reduce the variance of the estimator. Since you are using the discounted reward, subtracting the mean says at every step, if I got less than the average, penalize that action, otherwise encourage it. The scaling might just result in another equivalent step size. Generally one simple baseline is mean of rewards obtained so far throughout the game, but I guess these guys are considering only this batch for some reason.

As for your 3rd point, what you are actually estimating is the discounted sum over $r_i$ as you said. The recursive equation helps you compute the discounted reward starting from $i^{th}$ timestep till the end of the episode. We only have access to the per step rewards, so if you want the discounted sum for every timestep $i$ till end of the episode, we do this recursive estimation.

A naive way to do that would be with $n$ for loops, each going from index $i$ till $n$

Comment: my main issue is that we are scaling with respect to the recursive version of rewards, look at the code. How does that make any sense? It seems like non-sense to me.

Comment: why would the value function grow? I don't understand. (I also got this code from policy gradient code so I'm not sure if value functions are used at all)

Comment: Looking at it more closely, In policy gradients, we subtract something called a 'baseline', which helps reduce the variance of the estimator. Since you are using the discounted reward, subtracting the mean says at every step, if I got less than the average, penalize that action, otherwise encourage it. The scaling might just result in another equivalent step size.  Generally one simple baseline is mean of rewards obtained so far throughout the game, but I guess these guys are considering only this batch for some reason.

Comment: sorry but your failing to address my main concern which is that we take the average of the discounted rewards, rather than the individual rewards. In supervised we have $\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} loss_i $. But here this is not what we have. Thats what is driving my main confusion.

Comment: Here, you have a monte carlo approximation to the value function. The baseline which you subtract to reduce variance is defined wrt this - the discounted sum, not the individual rewards.

Comment: what do u mean by baseline?

Comment: the baseline is the thing you subtract from the discounted sum. I encourage you to look at http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture14.pdf - the REINFORCE part

Comment: Thnx! Do you mind explaining in more detail the monte carlo estimate of the value function? It seems the estimate is of a bunch of NONE iid samples which seems super fishy to me.

Comment: was the link to CS231 for baseline or for the monte-carlo estimate of the value function? (the thing I see as weird average using R instead of r i.e. the recursive average thing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89908/discussion-between-sridhar-thiagarajan-and-pinocchio).